# Gimp: center layer on another

Tags: gimp

I have two layers. The background layer is way bigger than the front layer (which contains an image).

I want to center the front layer horizontally and vertically on the background layer.

I can't get it to work with `Image -> Align Visible Layers...`
How to do this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Use [the Align Tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-align.html) to align layers with respect to other layers.  Note that this tool is dependent on the actual layer size/extent, not the image size.  In GIMP the layer size can be bigger than the image size. If the user manual isn't doing it for you, look up tutorials for using that tool on Youtube. There's [a good one here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maDlaexrdac). I have no affiliation with that youtuber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Yields:

[image]

Of course all this is really based on the layers borders and not the layer opaque contents, so you lay want to do `Layer>Autocrop layer` first.